# how does Firefox use plugins and how can i use plugins in other applications?

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon

I've a plugin on my Firefox which i'm trying to figure out how it works to build a system application version of the plugin. i can see Firefox uses a DLL through plugin-container to use the plugin and i'm able to sniff some function calls between them. but i'm not sure how the plugin actually works?

Is there any metadata in Firefox for plugin DLLs?

can i determine function details inside plugin DLL?

Answer (score 0):

Plugins, like flash and unity, are compiled binaries and most often proprietary. These aren't like add-ons that are written in JavaScript, and can be read and understood by users.